# How to get GUID:CMDId combination of a Git Branch Context menu in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to create a VS 2022 extension. I wanted to add a new item to the context menu that appears when user right clicks on any branch in the View->Git Repository Window and in the Git Changes Window.

I know that the GUID is {57735d06-c920-4415-a2e0-7d6e6fbdfa99}
But I am unable to find the command ID.

I have tried installing the command explorer but it was not showing the data related to menu groups.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cnaB.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

I have found that the CmdID of a command in the commit history window to be 0Xf040
I am trying with values from 0Xf001 till 0Xf100. No luck.

I know this is brute force approach, but found no other good way

Comment: It is 0x1005. It is not stored in a local file. From the source code, we can get it. See my answer. :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, I have tried with the ID 0x1005. The new menu was not added to the Git changes sub-menu or Git Branches window

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the command id you want.

It is 0x1005.

How do I get it:

Just read the sample open-source code of Microsoft here:

https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/83759e1796f6cb9bfc509b58d7c1c0099ad5210d/CodeLensOopSample/src/CodeLensOopProvider/GitCommitDataPointProvider.cs#L104C33-L104C44

You can see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After spending 4+ hours searching, finally found it inside the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.dll, Here is the answer you are looking for:

```
<GuidSymbol name="PackageCommandSetGuid" value="{57735d06-c920-4415-a2e0-7d6e6fbdfa99}">
<IDSymbol value="0xF0D9" name="GitBranches_ActiveRepositoriesSection_ContextMenu" />
```

[GitBranches_ActiveRepositoriesSection_ContextMenu ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GaVT.png)